# streamwriter not writing into the file

Tags: c#

```
string directoryPath = @"D:\Tools\Examples";
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\MacbethTest.txt",true))
{
    foreach (string rawImagePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.raw").Select(Path.GetFullPath))
    {
       image.ReadHeaderLessImage(rawImagePath, width, height, colorOrder, bpp);

       List<MacbethCheckerBatchesColor> resultWithOutExtraLines =
       wrapper.DetectMacbethColorChecker(image.Data, image.Width, image.Height, image.ColorOrder,
                                         image.Bpp, showResult, batchFillFactor);
           if (resultWithOutExtraLines == null)
           {
                file.WriteLine(rawImagePath);
           }
     }
 }
```

here is my code I'm trying to write the name of the files which are not working well into a file.
the file turns out empty. althought I hit the file.writeline line.

 can you see my mistake?
I followed this example
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: you are getting any errors?

Comment: can you open the `StreamWriter` inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: no errors, I will try to open is inside.

Comment: hmm, perhaps you can do a Console.WriteLine for rawImagePath and see if that prints anything? could be that you're writing properly but not having any strings to write

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh it worked. now it's writing into file.

Comment: @matrixanomaly I did it, it prints

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Why would you open the streamwriter inside the foreach? That will keep opening and closing it - it will work (as you have set it to append) but there is no reason why the original code wouldn't work.

Comment: @LeeWillis but it doesn't work..

Comment: I took the code, pasted it into an empty solution, modified the bits that needed it (paths, etc) and it worked. If you try to view the file while the code is running it will be empty as it may not have flushed to file. If you view it when the using statement is run it will have records.

Comment: @LeeWillis please share what you did

Comment: I can't post it as a comment. I will put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
            string directoryPath = @"D:\Tools\Examples";
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\MacbethTest.txt", true) { AutoFlush = true })
        {
            foreach (string rawImagePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.raw").Select(t => Path.GetFullPath(t)))
            {
                image.ReadHeaderLessImage(rawImagePath, width, height, colorOrder, bpp);

                List<MacbethCheckerBatchesColor> resultWithOutExtraLines =
                wrapper.DetectMacbethColorChecker(image.Data, image.Width, image.Height, image.ColorOrder,
                                                  image.Bpp, showResult, batchFillFactor);
                if (resultWithOutExtraLines == null)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(rawImagePath);
                }
            }
        }
```

Or this:

```
            string directoryPath = @"D:\Tools\Examples";
        foreach (string rawImagePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.raw").Select(Path.GetFullPath))
        {
            image.ReadHeaderLessImage(rawImagePath, width, height, colorOrder, bpp);
            List<MacbethCheckerBatchesColor> resultWithOutExtraLines =
            wrapper.DetectMacbethColorChecker(image.Data, image.Width, image.Height, image.ColorOrder,
                                              image.Bpp, showResult, batchFillFactor);
            if (resultWithOutExtraLines == null)
            {
                File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\MacbethTest.txt", new[] { rawImagePath });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you have posted should work.

If you're trying to check the contents of the file while the code is running (for instance if you have set a breakpoint), the stream will not have been flushed, meaning it won't have actually written anything to the file yet.

If you want to see the contents of the file during debug, you should call the `Flush` method after `WriteLine` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 file.WriteLine(rawImagePath);
 file.Flush();
 // add a breakpoint after here: the file will have contents
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer  - please read the comments above before downvoting!

Change the paths to something that works on your system

```
        static void Main (string[] args) {

            string directoryPath = @"F:\logs";
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"f:\development\testing.txt", true)) {
                foreach (string rawImagePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.log").Select(Path.GetFullPath)) {
                    //image.ReadHeaderLessImage(rawImagePath, width, height, colorOrder, bpp);

/*
                    List<MacbethCheckerBatchesColor> resultWithOutExtraLines =
                    wrapper.DetectMacbethColorChecker(image.Data, image.Width, image.Height, image.ColorOrder,
                                                      image.Bpp, showResult, batchFillFactor);
*/
                    //if (resultWithOutExtraLines == null) {
                        file.WriteLine(rawImagePath);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

So the `bottomline` is `open` the `StreamWriter` inside the loop.

```
 string directoryPath = @"D:\Tools\Examples";

        foreach (string rawImagePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.raw").Select(Path.GetFullPath))
        {
          using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\MacbethTest.txt",true))
           {
           image.ReadHeaderLessImage(rawImagePath, width, height, colorOrder, bpp);

           List<MacbethCheckerBatchesColor> resultWithOutExtraLines =
           wrapper.DetectMacbethColorChecker(image.Data, image.Width, image.Height, image.ColorOrder,
                                             image.Bpp, showResult, batchFillFactor);
               if (resultWithOutExtraLines == null)
               {
                    file.WriteLine(rawImagePath);
               }
           }
         }
```

Comment: No, don't open the streamwriter inside a loop. If you have a large loop it will be opening and closing constantly. If you set the append flag to false then it will keep overwriting the records.

Comment: @LeeWillis I get what you are saying but the other code doesn't work. the append flags should be set to true because I want to append the answers

Comment: Then there is something else wrong. This might be an acceptable solution for you but it isn't an answer to the problem in general, and will likely confuse someone in the future.